# How to style nested Angular components?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am wondering what is the proper/recommended way of doing the following:

I have an angular component which is at a particular route.  For the sake of example, lets say the route is:

```
/main-page
```

When this route is being viewed, the template spans the entire width of the screen.  Now lets say I have a button inside this page that when clicked goes to a new, nested route.  Lets call this route:

```
/main-page/with-sidebar
```

When I click on this button, I want the main page to be squeezed into the left 70% of the screen and I want the view for my sidebar to be on the right 30%.

My first attempt to make this happen was to put a class on the element containing the main page called "shrinkable" and then put:

```
.shrinkable {
    width: 70%;
}
```

into the stylesheet for my "with-sidebar" component (because I only want this style to be applied when I'm actually in the sub-route.  The problem with this however is that Angular (or maybe it's scss?) modifies my stylesheet in a way that it will only ever apply to elements within the component (or sub-component in my case).   Generally speaking this is a great feature for making components re-usable, but in my case it's preventing me from doing what I need to do.

I suspect I am going about this the wrong way.  Advice?

Note, to clarify this is Angular 5 I'm using.

Comment: Nothing fancy, just disciplined CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551634/1440240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<a routerLink="child"
[ngStyle]="{'color': router.url === '/sample/child' ? 'red' : 'green' }">
Navigate to Child route</a>
```

to conditionally style components. Here is an example I created for yoU:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcn94k?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: While this does in fact work. it still doesn't solve my problem.  What happens now is if i click the button, the main view shrinks to 70% but if i click the back button it stays at 70% forever.   I think my entire approach to this might be wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah, I hadn't considered that. Then your best bet is to use [ngStyle] to set two different widths depending on a condition i.e. which route you are on.

Comment: That sounds promising.  gonna read up on it and get back to you if it works.

Comment: See my updated answer for an example I created for you.

Comment: This works for me!.  took me a while to figure out because i forgot to import the Router into my parent component.  Once i had that it was all good.  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar by creating a "shell" component to hold the two panels. Then used the bootstrap column styles to put them into two columns.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <pm-product-shell-list></pm-product-shell-list>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
        <pm-product-shell-detail></pm-product-shell-detail>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then route to this shell component to display both components side by side.

The result looks like this:

[image]

You can find the complete source code for this app here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Communication

You could also replace the second child component with a child router outlet if you wanted to route additional components into that location.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <pm-product-shell-list></pm-product-shell-list>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good structure that i should probably use, however it doesn't handle the dynamic width problem