# How can I use 1 css file for n .ts file in proper way?

Tags: angular

May be it is easy question but I would like to know proper way of this.
Can I create .css file without .ts file and use this .css file for several component?

For example I have 3 component and if I want to use common css for only these 3 component , what should I do?

Other question if I want to use common css file for them but additionaly if I want one of them to use its own css file and additionaly use common .css file, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The `styleUrls` property inside the `@Component` decorator is an array, and it can accept several stylesheet files:

```
styleUrls: ['@commons/commons-style.css', './app.component.css'];
```

And do the same in any file where you want to import the common style. The order can matter, since the style is applied on cascade.

Comment: Thank you, and what do you offer for a css that is used for 3 component, which folder I have to put css file for this 3 component?

Comment: You can put it in any folder. Usually many teams adopt a `CommonModule` with all the shared definitions. But it doesn't really matter, so put it where it's logical for you

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do in my Angular app: [Here's a rough [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-template) example]

**Styles within /scss/ are kept one level deep and meant to be reused 
everywhere.** .

[image]

**/blocks/** contains dedicated blocks of styles such as inputs, buttons, etc.
**/global/** contains sitewide layout and MQs: base.scss, 768up.scss, etc.
**/helpers/** contains SCSS variables mixins, etc.
**/includes/** contains resets, normalize, animations, etc.

Sync variables by importing them in component.scss files.

```
@import '../../../../scss/includes/variables';
```

By staying 1 level deep in global styles the cascade can reset these styles for you (with a 1-level-deep rule)

**This setup fundamentally solves many Angular CSS issues such as:**

- shadow-piercing styles exist in the global scope
- resetting any component styles happens within the component
- styling child components from within parent components is easy
- no need for deprecated `::ng-deep`
- manageable / DRY CSS scalability without specificity deepening
- one reusable SCSS variables file
- lighter weight component styles (containing only reset styles)

Answer (score -1):

You can do what Cristian says, but also on the `angular.json` file you can include the `css` among the styles array, but that'd affect all the components, that's the only downside.